# How to deal with deadlocks using ReentrantReadWriteLock in microservices

Tags: concurrency, spring-data-jpa, deadlock

We have a deadlock situation which occured because of this heavy load on the microservice (Say A) causing multiple requests from different client services (B,C). So these calls from B and C come for the same clientId(key) and are served by different instances of A and they try to update the same clientId data in database at same time causing below error.

```
CannotAcquireLockException is thrown,
(SQL Error: 60, SQLState: 61000..
ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource
```

We have decided to implement sharding at load balancer(haproxy) level which will ensure same instance of A will always serve the requests from B and C for a specific key(clientId), so we dont have multiple instances processing the request for same key(clientId).

Now we get into the mode of everything in single jvm as we have made sure requests from B and C for a specific clientId always come to same instance of A.

With this its still possible that requests from B and C services come for same clientId with difference in time of nanoseconds. Any then multiple threads will again try to update the same clientId data in database at same time causing same error again.

To improve this we are looking for possible solutions and one solutions is ReentrantReadWriteLock which should take care of this based on the concepts.

We are using spring data jpa and have a save being done which looks like

```
clientJpaRepository.save(ClientObject);
```

Now is it possible to use something like below.

```
public void save(Client clientObject) {
   String clientId = clientObject.getClientId();
   try {
      boolean isLockAcquired = writeLock.tryLock(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
      if (isLockAcquired) {
         clientJpaRepository.save(clientObject);
      }
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      log.error("exception occured trying to acquire lock for clientId={}", clientId);
   } finally {
      writeLock.unlock();
   }
}
```

I am not very sure how its going to deal with the keys. As in i don't want any threads to block if they are wanting to update for different key(clientId 2).
Also, other thing to note is there could be reads happening as part of other API calls for this data from database. They would not be waiting too long hopefully and i hope i don't need to make any changes there for the reads. 
Sorry for the long question, Hope i will hear from someone soon.
Thanks.

Comment: Having a single application lock for all keys is going to kill throughput, which probably a bad idea.

You should first clarify what is actually causing the deadlock? If they try to update the same data this is not sufficient for a deadlock. They must update two pieces of data in different order. Are they? Why?

Comment: @JensSchauder hi, There are 2 lists of objects being saved by 2 threads. Since we are using jpa, we call jpa repository.save(list); since the calls are for the same clientId(key) we are saving list of items in each of the threads. Since it is a list unless all records are inserted Oracle doesnot commit and both threads are doing same thing and causing a deadlock

Comment: This should be fixable by ordering the elements before saving (save one at a time and flushing immediatly).

Comment: @JensSchauder could you elaborate that a little please. Or give some links on how to go about solving this?

Comment: If you are dealing with the single table deadlock can not appear when rows are always updated in the same order. JPA doesn't guarantee the order of execution therefore you'd have to force it by first ordering the list of items that are getting processed and then forcing JPA to execute them one by one, i.e. doing a flush after each. This might harm performance a little but probably will still be way faster then dealing with application side locks.